# Verilog: tristates for synthesis, and difference between conditional and case?

Tags: verilog, synthesis, tri-state-logic

How do I convert a tristate bus to 2-state logic for synthesis?

I've made a little test

```
module test1( inout tristate, output flattened);
    assign flattened = tristate ? 1 : 0;
endmodule

module test2( inout tristate, output reg flattened);
    always @(tristate) begin
        case(tristate)
            0:          flattened = 0;
            default: flattened = 1;
        endcase
    end
endmodule

`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module test_tb;
    reg tristateEnable;
    reg tristateValue;
    wire tristate = tristateEnable ? tristateValue : 1'bz;
    wire flattened1, flattened2;

    test1 uut1(tristate, flattened1);
    test2 uut2(tristate, flattened2);

    initial begin
        tristateValue = 1'b0;
        tristateEnable = 1;
        #10 tristateValue = 1'b1;
        #10 tristateEnable = 1'b0;
    end

endmodule
```

Simulating it I got that module test1 sets `flattened` to X and module test2 sets it to 1, the latter is what I wanted, but I haven't synthesized it yet. Is there a better / standard way of doing this?

Comment: I simulated your tests using VCS, the results simulation results are identical for test1 and test2. Can you please elaborate your intent? I think test1 might be preferable, just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've asked two questions: (1) what is the difference between the conditional operator and the case statement, and (2) how to handle tri-state values.

On the language question:

In short, Verilog has a 4-state data type, and the operators handle the 4 states differently.

1. The case statement does a "4-state test", otherwise known as "case equality". The case expression (`tristate` in your example) is compared against `0`, `1`, `x`, and `z`. When it is `z`, the default branch is taken, so `flattened` is `1`, as you found.
2. The conditional ('ternary') operator also does a 4-state test, and finds `tristate` as `z`. It doesn't know what to do now, so it combines the two values you supplied (`0` and `1`) into a resulting `x`, which is what you see. Basically, it's trying to be smart. See table 5-21 in the 2005 LRM.
   Note that the `if` statement does *not* do a 4-state test.

Tristates: you're confused because your *control* signal (`tristate`) goes to `z`; it's the *data* signal (`flattened`) that should go to `z`.
You don't 'flatten' tristates for synthesis; you normally model a pull-up or pull-down. This will be specific to your technology, but you may just need to instantiate a pullup or pulldown component. Your synthesiser may or may not do this automatically for you if you have code like

```
assign sig_o = (ena == 1'b1)? sig_i : 1'bz;
```

You need to read your synthesiser docs to be sure. Note that you should only ever use a conditional operator like this if `ena` is guaranteed to be 2-state (`0`/`1`).

Comment: In my case, I am conecting to an external usb controller with a 32-bit bidirectional communication line. My simplified connection scheme would be:

`module communications(inout data_bus, input out_stream, output in_stream, ..)
  ....
  assign data_bus = (en_data_bus) ? out_stream :1'bz;
  assign in_stream = databus;
  ...
endmodule`

It simulates without problems, but in_stream gets optimized out in synthesis. Since I cant use tristates internally in the fpga im trying to force in_stream to 2-state.

Comment: If it's being optimised out it has nothing to do with tristates - it's because you're not using it, so it's not necessary. It also looks like there may be some confusion in your in/out directions, and possibly your module connections.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. In my code it's actively using it so it may be a chained optimization thing. Anyway, the original question is answered, thank you!

Comment: @eml for point number 1, can we use casez to ignore all the `z` design?

Comment: On using `casez` to ignore all `z`'s in design: you could, but it's not a good idea. See www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG1999SJ_SynthMismatch.pdf, section 4.4. You can't leave floating nodes in your design anyway, so just make sure that everything is pulled up or down. For an input or an I/O, make sure that you instantiate a cell which has a pull up or down.